# Is there a function that can tell the Keras model to omit certain parts of a picture while classifying?

Tags: python, image, keras, classification

At the moment I am creating a model where pictures of eyes with possible Diabetic Retinopathy need to be classified. To do this, I created a Keras model in python and did my best on structuring the model. With Grad Cam, I am able to see what the model looks at and the reason for the classification. Here an example:

[image: Example of Grad-CAM]

As you can see, the model clearly focuses on the corner of the picture. Apparently, the model thinks that black corner of the image is a characteristic for one class or multiple classes.

Now my question was, is there a way to tell the model to omit the black corners of the image? I think it would improve my model a lot since those black corners are in almost every picture and seeing that black corner as a weight for the classification makes no sense.

This is how my model looks now:

[image: Model layers]

For preprocessing I used CLAHE and to normalize my classes, I used horizontal flipping.

If there is anything unclear, let me know!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you quickly explain what `GradCAM` does? e.g. What does red mean? Is it that the gradients were high for that region?

Comment: Ofcourse, GradCAM uses the gradients of any target concept, flowing into the final convolutional layer to produce a coarse localization map highlighting important regions in the image for predicting the concept. So yes, red indeed means that region was important when classifying

Comment: Is CLAHE a canonical preprocessing step for this kind of data? Did you try simple preprocessing methods like x - x_mean ?

Comment: CLAHE was used to improve the contrast of the picture. We did not try x - x mean, because after CLAHE it already looked fine. Also I think it does not solve the 'black corner problem'.

Comment: This seems like a problem that needs to be solved using the preprocessing you are using. If you don't like using x - x_mean you can try other preprocessing methods. But x-x_mean is something that works well accross many problems.

Comment: You know how to implement x-x_mean while using ImageDataGenerator?

Comment: That's easy, read [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/). You just got a set `featurewise_center` or `samplewise_center` depending on your need.